# Blank values printing as zero in Excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a report that looks similar to this:

[image]

I have a formula that is calculating an average of cells that represent January through December (YEARLY AVERAGE column). However, I do not want to take into consideration months that we have not hit, yet. For example, the formula/code to calculate average:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('N' . $i,'=AVERAGE(B' . $i . ':M' . $i .')');
```

`$i` represents the line I'm iterating through to dynamically populate my report. For ease:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('N4','=AVERAGE(B4:M4)');
```

The JAN-DEC report data is derived from an array that I have built that looks like:

```
array(12) {
  [1]=>
  int(0)
  [2]=>
  int(0)
  [3]=>
  int(0)
  [4]=>
  int(0)
  [5]=>
  int(0)
  [6]=>
  int(0)
  [7]=>
  int(0)
  [8]=>
  int(0)
  [9]=>
  string(15) "176.80000000000"
  [10]=>
  string(15) "707.61290322580"
  [11]=>
  string(0) ""
  [12]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

My last two array values that represent NOV and DEC are `""` values, however they are being printed as zeros in the report.

My question, is this some sort of formatting I need to adjust when printing to the document? IE:

```
foreach(range('B','M') as $columnID){
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($columnID . $i, round($data[$k],2));             
}
```

Or do I need to store the value differently when building my array? IE:

```
if($m <= (int)$this_month){
    $data[$m] = 0;
}
else{                           
    $data[$m] = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of

```
round($data[$k],2))
```

will convert that empty string to a float, that's what [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) does

If you want to retain the empty string, then don't try rounding the value, and the standard PHP way to do that is to use an `if` test and round or don't round accordingly